# Reusing Audacity source code

Tags: c#, reusability, audacity

I would like to ask, has anyone successfully reused Audacity's source code in their own program? I am trying to reuse the playing, recording and displaying waveform function of Audacity, but do not know how to do so because of its association with wxwidgets. I am thinking of a few concepts:
1. Compile the whole Audacity as a dll and call it in my C# program.(is it possible?)
2. Extract out the functions of playing, recording and displaying waveform and compile them into dll to be used in my C# program.
Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to code, if you haven't already, consider the licensing implications for your software.

Comment: licensing is not a problem as it is an open source software

Comment: Open source != free source. Licensing still applies. Audacity is GPLv2.

Comment: okay. even so, it is not meant for commercial use.

Comment: Commercial use or not doesn't have anything to do with the requirement of releasing your source code.  You can do this commercially, or not.  Read the GPLv2 here:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html